# Ubuntu 20.04LTS is taking automatically screen shots

Tags: 20.04

While turning on the laptop it is somewhat slow and after using it for some time it is taking screenshots automatically and saving it to pictures folder.

Comment: You may have a stuck key..

Answer (score 1):

You might need some knowledge of which application accessing those directory. I think tool like `lsof` may help you. Something like `lsof ~/screenshots`

Answer (score 0):

I would try blowing some compressed air under the **Print Screen** key (probably **PrtSc** or similar, near the top). If you don't have anything to blow air under it, when the laptop is off I would carefully use a pin or opened-up paperclip to get out any fluff or accumulated dust from under the key. In my experience, this has always been the case (except for when a keyboard is dying).